# How do I make Pixel Perfect Camera scale like Normal Camera in Unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, scale, pixel, perfect

[This is my scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlp7w.png)

Right now if I use resolutions that aren't 16:9 the Pixel Perfect Camera [zooms out quite a lot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gu5Am.png) showing parts that shouldn't be shown.

How do I get it to scale like the Normal Camera which just [cuts out parts outside the borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGIGY.png)?

The Reference Resolution is currently set to 320x180, I tried changing the Reference Resolution to other resolutions (640x360, etc) but that changed nothing.

Tried Pixel Snapping on/off.

Cropping the X and Y does a good job at hiding the outside borders places but [makes the screen too small](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XejkR.png) for non 16:9 resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

The way I dealt with this was to:

-Temporarily disable upscale render texture on the camera.

-Zoom the camera changing the orthographic size progressively on Update function.

-When zoom is finished, re enable the upscale render texture, changing the resolution to a different one at the same time.

Note that the new resolution, needs to make what's on your screen, bigger or smaller depending on if your are zooming in or out.
To make the process smoother you can find out the orthographic size on different resolutions and set that target when zooming.